# Divide using formula from different table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to evaluate a formula in sql server 2008

Table 1 contains

```
Entity  Value
A       2424053.500000
B       1151425.412500
C       484810.700000
```

Table 2 contains

```
Entity  Formula
A       (2100*(1-0.0668)*24*mday*10) 
B       (1000*(1-0.0575)*24*mday*10)
C       (1260*(1-0.09)*24*mday*10)
```

Where mday is number of days taken from user. Data type of Formula is a string.

I need to calculate the output of value/formula for each entity
can you provide me the query for the same

Comment: what is the datatype of the columns in `Table 2`?

Answer (score 0):

Example solution for SQL Server 2008, adjust as required...

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE object_id = object_id('EntityValue'))
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE EntityValue;
END;

CREATE TABLE EntityValue
(
    Id CHAR(1),
    mdayValue DECIMAL(13, 6)
)

INSERT INTO EntityValue
    VALUES ('1', 2424053.500000)
    , ('2', 1151425.412500)
    , ('3', 484810.700000)

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE object_id = object_id('EntityFormula'))
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE EntityFormula;
END;

CREATE TABLE EntityFormula
(
    Id CHAR(1),
    Formula NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO EntityFormula
    VALUES ('1', '(2100*(1-0.0668)*24*mday*10)')
    , ('2', '(1000*(1-0.0575)*24*mday*10)')
    , ('3', '(1260*(1-0.09)*24*mday*10)')


DECLARE @FormulaTable AS TABLE
    (
        RowId INT IDENTITY(1,1)
        ,Formula NVarchar(max)
    );

INSERT INTO @FormulaTable (Formula)
SELECT Formula = REPLACE(eFormula.Formula, 'mday', CAST(eValue.mdayValue AS NVARCHAR(MAX)))
FROM EntityFormula AS eFormula
    INNER JOIN EntityValue AS eValue ON eValue.ID = eFormula.ID;

DECLARE @TSql NVarchar(max), @CurrentRowId INT;
SET @CurrentRowId = 1;
WHILE(1=1)
BEGIN

    SELECT @TSql = 'SELECT ' + Formula
    FROM @FormulaTable
    WHERE RowID = @CurrentRowId

    IF(@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
    BEGIN
        BREAK;
    END

    EXEC sp_executesql @Tsql

    SET @CurrentRowId = @CurrentRowId + 1;
END
```

Comment: I do not have the liberty to use cursors or loops...also you are replacing the mday with the value from the first table..mday will be a input fromt the user say 'mday = 31' ..i need to divide the value in the first table with the computed value of the formula

Comment: Sorry you did not state how the two tables were related or would be used. Not sure how you would achieve this without some form of string manipulation and SQL execution.